# Real/Resident memory larger than allocations reported by XCode Instruments

Tags: macos, cocoa, memory-management, xcode-instruments

I'm i little bit lost. I'm writing a little app whichs load in the first step a bunch of data and put these into the database.

For every entry in the database i create a new object which hopefully get released from the arc :-).

The instrument tools shows me that my app has actually 5-6 mb living allocations. But the activity monitor says i'm actually using 100 mb of the 'physikal' (Real) memory?

How can i reduce the 100 mb?  The memory leak your are seeing are only 100 kb, thats not the reason!?

### Instruments shows 5.67Mb 'Live'

[image: Instruments]

### Activity Monitor shows 98Mb Real memory

[image: Activity Monitor]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is — *Don't worry about it-100Mb isn't a lot*.

The main thing you need to know here is that 'Real' or *Resident* RAM is not at all the same thing as allocated RAM.  They can become linked if you allocate a lot of RAM, but you didn't.

**Why aren't they the same?**

- De-allocated (or garbage collected) RAM is often not returned to the OS, so can still be 'resident' for a while.

  **This is most likely to be the culprit in your case** - loading the database in allocated a lot of memory (1Gb transitory) for a little while, then deallocated it, leaving a whole lot of RAM resident in your process.

  Note that in *garbage collection* (including *ARC*) the memory space allocated for an object can live for longer than the object it once held - e.g. If you allocate and immediately release 10000 1K objects you may find your real RAM has to go up 10Mb, even though only 1K of data was being used at any moment.  This is because garbage collection is deferred until a special clean-up phase of your program's run-loop.
- Resident RAM can only be requested in 4Kb pages, this means as much as 4Kb of resident RAM might be allocated even for a 1 byte allocation.  Typically malloc tries to place multiple allocations on the same 4k page but you will see some loss due to fragmentation.
- allocated RAM that is not currently in-use can be paged out to disk, thus no longer resident
- the application includes some (possibly *lots of*) memory which isn't 'allocated' by malloc, this includes:

  - the application binary - code and data
  - application libraries - in private or shared RAM
  - the stack
  - Other shared memory
  - Possibly graphics area (e.g. X11), open file buffers and mmaps (depending on what we consider 'allocated'.
  - for a desktop or laptop; for an embedded device it is a lot, and for a phone or tablet it depends.